# How to refresh List from Database without refreshing the Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to update my list as soon as a new entry is included into my table.
Tried using $interval service,but after the callback the controller isn't getting loaded.

```
$scope.displayNotification=function(){
           NavbarService.displayNotification()
           .then(function(response){
               angular.forEach(response,function(val,key){
                   if(key == 'success'){
                       $scope.notificationList= val;
                       alert("Hi");
                       console.log($scope.notificationList);
                       if(null != $scope.notificationList && undefined !=$scope.notificationList){
                           $scope.notificationCount = $scope.notificationList.length;
                       }
                   }
               });
           },function(){
              // console.error("Error while fetching Notification");
           });
       }
```

used this to callback the function after an interval

```
intervalPromise = $interval($scope.displayNotification, 3000);
```

calling this Function for getting the data from my table.

Here is the http call

```
function displayNotification() {
            var defer = $q.defer(); 
            var url='api/notify';
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : url,
                data :  {}
            }).success( function(response, status,config, headers) {
                defer.resolve(response);
            }).error(function(errResp) {
                defer.reject({ message:"No Notification Details" });
            });

    return defer.promise;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

** Upated answer with incapsulation (safeapply) **

Try using this safeapply hack:

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

Try calling it like this:

```
$scope.safeApply(function() {
    $scope.notificationCount = $scope.notificationList.length;
});
```

or like this:

```
$scope.notificationCount = $scope.notificationList.length;
$scope.safeApply();
```

ref: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js

Comment: No! doesn't helps. Got this Error In console. Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: I tried updating the answer now, does it work with safeapply? Please upvote if it works :)